# Registering One Button Press with a GPIO button in C#

Tags: c#, button, raspberry-pi, gpio

The following code is giving me a small issue.

```
  public void ButtonShort()
    {
        lcd.WriteLine(" K ");
        GpioPinValue Readbutton = ButtonS.Read();
        if (buttonS == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            Temp = Temp + "K";
        }
    }
```

Temp is a list which is empty by default. So every button press should add ONE 'K'. 
But it actually registers 'K' multiple times.

What I want is that one button press only registers one 'K'.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seems that `ButtonShort`is called too often. As long as the button is pressed, each call to `ButtonShort`will add one "K".

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly help you for C#, but had a similar problem once where I used Java with the Pi4J Lib for the GPIO Access.

In there, you have events which are triggered by a changing input pin value. I catched that event and checked in the routine wether the state was high/low, depending on what had to be the actual trigger for counting.

Code in Java was quite straigt forward:

```
public void handleGpioPinInputStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getState() == PinState.HIGH) { 
        [...]
    }
}
```

[Edit - got interested... :-)]

Perhaps the following code from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/pushbutton) will help:

```
private void buttonPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // toggle the state of the LED every time the button is pressed
    if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
    {
        ledPinValue = (ledPinValue == GpioPinValue.Low) ? 
        GpioPinValue.High : GpioPinValue.Low;
        ledPin.Write(ledPinValue);
    }
[...]
```